# Form software for actors

Tags: forms, hosted

I run a film company and I'm looking for a better way for my actors to sign up for a part/character.

I want to have a form system where the actors are given a selection of available roles to select. When a part has already been reserved by someone else, that part wouldn't be available to select.

Is this possible with any online service?

Comment: Your title says "forum" and your post says "form", these are very different things.  Do you want it to be a website or an actual software that you install on your computer(in reference to your software ask in the title)

Comment: @New-To-IT Sorry, I'm talking about an online form that you fill out.

Comment: it's no problem, I just wanted to clarify before people started answering.  As you could get very different results for each one :)

Comment: What is wrong with normal application software like [greenhouse](http://www.greenhouse.io/) or [workday](http://www.workday.com/)?  When a role is filled you remove it from the "jobs" available to apply for.

Comment: "the actors are given a selection of available roles to select. When a part has already been reserved by someone else, that part wouldn't be available to select" ??? You don't have  a casting director? don't you find that everyone wants to star?

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at https://yamdu.com

This is a production management software. One feature is "Crew Management". That may be worth a look.